# MySQL Regexp to repeat CSV limits at 340 commas

Tags: mysql, regex, csv, mariadb, capture-group

I am trying to create regexp to validate comma separated name value pairs which starts from ID like so

```
select
'ID,2190,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def,abc,def'

regexp 
'^ID,[1-9][0-9]*(,[^,]+,[^,]*)*$'
```

the above query will output 0 istead of 1, but if i reduce a pair `,abc,def` this will reduce number of commas and the query will output 1

I have tried changing server, on a shared server the query runs fine irrespective of number of values

Can anyone tell me, is my query failing because of server configuration or something wrong in my regexp pattern, here i am trying to repeat a capture group 0 to infinite times

Comment: Seems OK. Maybe a problem of limitations? On reducing the length of the select string the regex is faster and needs less steps - see [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/QQMph6/1) to check your regex. -  You should give some more information about your server.

Comment: don't you think this is an abuse of regex in sql? consider to use stored function instead

Comment: @RickJames got it wrong, looked at different limit of a application to mysql... deleted the bogus comment

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use non-capturing group `(?:)` instead of capturing group `()`

```
'^ID,[1-9][0-9]*(?:,[^,]+,[^,]*)*$'
```

the comment from Andy was useful with regex101 link where in description it states you should use non-capturing group when the data is not important

> A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations or use a non-capturing group instead if you're not interested in the data

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE col REGEXP '^ID,[1-9][0-9]*'
  AND ( LENGTH(col) -
        LENGTH(REPLACE(col, ',', '')) ) % 2 = 0
```

The second part checks whether there are an even number of commas in `col`.  (Change `0` to `1` if you need an odd number.)

This formulation probably achieves your goal faster and avoids any regexp size limitation.